# what's delimited_payload_string fieldtype in solr

Tags: json, solr, schema, fieldtype

I'm new to solr. Can someone explain what the `delimited_payload_string` field type is?

For example, can I store the following JSON object as a multi-valued  delimited_payload_string?

```
"classifications": [
{"code": "RESTAURANT", "names": [{"nameLocale": "en-US", "name": "restaurant"}, {"nameLocale": "en-US", "name": "fast food"}]}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A delimited payload string is for attaching a payload to a specific field - a payload is an additional value that isn't visible in the document, but can be used by custom plugins. From [Solr Payloads](https://lucidworks.com/2017/09/14/solr-payloads/)

> Available alongside the positionally related information is an optional general purpose byte array. At the lowest-level, Lucene allows any term in any position to store whatever bytes it’d like in its payload area. This byte array can be retrieved as the term’s position is accessed.
>
> [...]
>
> A payload’s primary use case is to affect relevancy scoring; there are also other very interesting ways to use payloads, discussed here later. Built-in at Lucene’s core scoring mechanism is float Similarity#computePayloadFactor() which until now has not been used by any production code in Lucene or Solr; though to be sure, it has been exercised extensively within Lucene’s test suite since inception. It’s hardy, just under-utilized outside custom expert-level coding to ensure index-time payloads are encoded the same way they are decoded at query time, and to hook this mechanism into scoring.

In your case you probably want to flatten the document before indexing and indexing the value as separate tags, depending on what you want to do with the data.

Comment: Thanks, but do you have any idea how I can flatten the nested json object automatically when I'm indexing the document ? cause when I do this in linux, it autmatically flatten it, however in windows I get error !

Comment: Solr should not behave differently between Windows and Linux. Are you using the same methods and indexing in the same way? The reference guide as a section about [indexing arbitrarily formed JSON](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/transforming-and-indexing-custom-json.html).

Comment: Thanks MatsLindh ! it's solved, the problem was that I was using \example\exampledocs\post.jar to index the document, but now I'm using the /update url using post method to index my data and it's flattening my nested object automatically and makes the fields.